# Code delivering the wrong result at higher inputs

Tags: java, string

I am an aspiring coder. I have been trying to solve this question on codechef. What do you reckon is the problem here? A link to the question: https://www.codechef.com/submit/EVENTUAL?tab=statement
My code fail when the input is 990, which, in the question refers to the value of n. The value of 'n' refers to the length of the string. My code for the question has been provided below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class eventual_reduction {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int t = in.nextInt();
        while(t-->0){
            long count =0;
            long n = in.nextInt();
            String str = in.next();
            if(n%2!=0){
                System.out.println("NO");
            }else{
                String s = str;
                for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                    if(s.charAt(0)==str.charAt(i)){
                        count++;
                        if((count+1)%2==0){
                            for(int j=1; j<n;j++){
                                if(s.charAt(j)==str.charAt(i)){
                                    count++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(count%2==0){
                    System.out.println("YES");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("NO");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Could you please help me out with the code? Would love to see ways to improve my code. Thank you!

Comment: What is the concise problem? What behaviour do you get, what do you expect instead?

Comment: what does the error say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to get the frequencies of all the letters in the string. If at least one of those frequencies is odd, you print *NO*, otherwise you print *YES*.

Let's analyze your code.

```java
String str = in.next();
```

I think this is more appropriate:

```java
String str = in.nextLine();
```

After calling `nextInt` and before calling `nextLine`, you need to add an extra call to `nextLine`

```java
long n = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
String str = in.nextLine();
```

Refer to [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

It seems like you want to iterate through each letter of `str` and for each letter, you iterate `str` again and count how many times it appears.

```java
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    if(s.charAt(0)==str.charAt(i)){
```

I don't understand the `if`. You are comparing every letter in `str` with the first letter in `str`. You simply need a nested `for` loop.

```java
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    int t = in.nextInt();
    while (t-- > 0) {
        long count = 0;
        long n = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        String str = in.nextLine();
        if (n % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
        else {
            String s = str;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                count = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    if (i != j) {
                        if (s.charAt(j) == str.charAt(i)) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (count % 2 == 1) {
                    System.out.println("NO");
                    count = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (count > 0) {
                if (count % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("YES");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("NO");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basicaly, in the nested `for` loops, we are comparing a given character, in `str`, with every other character in `str` and we repeat this for every character in `str`. Thus we count how many times each character appears in `str`. After obtaining the count, we check to see whether that count is odd. If it is then we print *NO*. After we have counted the occurrences of all the characters in `str`, we check whether we already printed *NO*. If we have not, then we check the final value of `count` to see whether it is even or odd and print *YES* or *NO*, respectively.

Alternatively, here is a solution that uses [streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        while (t-- > 0) {
            int n = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            String str = in.nextLine();
            if (n % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println("NO");
            }
            else {
                str.chars()
                   .boxed()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                                  Collectors.counting()))
                   .values()
                   .stream()
                   .filter(v -> v % 2 == 1)
                   .findFirst()
                   .ifPresentOrElse(v -> System.out.println("NO"),
                                    () -> System.out.println("YES"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. The characters in the string are converted to a stream of `int`s.
2. The stream of `int`s is converted to a stream of `Integer` objects.
3. A frequency map is created where the map key is [essentially] a letter and the map value is the number of occurrences of that letter in the string.
4. The map values, i.e. the letter frequencies, are searched for one that is odd.
5. If an odd frequency is found, *NO* is printed and if no odd frequencies are found, *YES* is printed.

The solution passed all the tests on [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/).